# Replacing an expression with a HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html

I need to parse a text (which contains XML tags) and then replace some of that tags for HTML spans with a specific class (to format it according). 
I can do that well when I add only one class to the span output, but when I add more than one class  it breaks completely.

I'm not trying to create two "class" attributes (I know that this wouldn't work), instead I'm just trying to concatenate: `"<span=\"en " + class + "<\"/span>"`, where `en` is the first class and `class` is a string variable.

When I didn't have to add this en class, I didn't use this `\"`, I simply put `"<span= " + class + "</span>"` and it worked fine. I'm not really sure about why this worked, since for me it would generate something like `"<span class=x> y </span>` in HTML, and the class attribute wouldn't work (because of the absence of `"`), but for some reason it works (and I would love to understand why).

The way I add this `<span>` to the HTML is through replace:

```
text = text.replace(exp, t);
document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = text;
```

Where `t` is that concatenation I mentioned above. As I have more than one XML tag to replace, I iterate this in a while until `(exp.exec(text) == null)`, though I don't believe the problem is there.

Can someone please explain to me what am I missing? I don't understand JS very well and don't know what might be happening. I wanted an explanation about what are the implications of what I am doing, because it is breaking another entirely different part of my code... The replace is still working (the output is `<span class="en x"> y </span>` as it should be), but then there's the strange part.

Since the only change I made was from `<span class="x"> y </span>` to `<span class="en x"> y </span>`, this shouldn't affect any other thing in my code (I will explain). I strongly believe that is has something to do with that escaped quotation marks, but I don't know how to make this work without them.

The part that breaks is:
I have a text loaded in a textarea of a form. This text is an XML. There's a "Visual Mode" button that activates my function (reads the entire text, replace the XML tags with colored spans). All's fine by now. But then, the user can go back to the textarea and edit the content of the text, adding, for example, more tagged words. And then click on "Visual Mode" again. The parsing went just fine when I was adding just one class.

But after I made that change, the parse fails to recognize the XML tags, and instead just takes the text as it is and pastes it! Then obviously everything breaks down. What I don't understand is why the parse stops working, because I have made no changes on how it reads the text, just on how it replaces it. I'm not even replacing the text on the same place from where I read, so one thing shouldn't affect another.

EDIT: 
My XML looks like:

```
<DOC DOCID="someid">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Aliquam at mauris <EM ID="someid" CATEG="somecateg">pellentesque </EM>, scelerisque purus condimentum, scelerisque purus. 
<EM ID="someid" CATEG="anothercateg">Mauris </EM>id libero vitae nulla fringilla vehicula. 
Integer varius  <EM ID="someid" CATEG="somecateg">lorem in </EM>nibh hendrerit facilisis. 
Nulla porttitor dui a lacus euismod bibendum. 
Proin in arcu eu magna laoreet suscipit id eget quam.
</DOC>
```

The XML contents is first loaded into a textarea (id "myid" in code bellow) and then manipulated after.

What I do is:

```
var exp = /<EM (.*?) <\/EM>/;
var text = document.getElementById("myid").value;
while(exp.exec(text) != null)
{
    var exp1 = /<EM ID=(.*?)<\/EM>/;
    var text1 = exp1.exec(text);
    var exp2 = /CATEG=\"(.*?)\"/;
    var text2 = exp2.exec(text1[1]);
    var categ = text2[1];
    var exp3 = /\">(.*?) <\/EM>/;
    var text3 = exp3.exec(text);
    var word = text3[1];
    var tag = "<span class=";
    var tag2 = ">";
    var tag3 = "</span> ";
    var t = tag + categ + tag2 + word + tag3;
    text = text.replace(exp, t);
}
document.getElementById("myid2").innerHTML = text;
```

So I extract the information I want from the tags and then replace them for a span with the corresponding class, which is then formatted accordingly (via CSS). Note that all the changes I do does not reflect on the textarea, instead they are put in a div (id "myid2" in code above). However, any changes done to the textarea does reflect on this div. So the user can add more words (tagged or not) or delete anything.

But as I mentioned in my post, the problem is when I try to put two categories. As my code is, `var tag = "<span class=";` is working fine, and the problem occurs when I change the code to:

```
var tag = "<span class=\"en ";
var tag2 = "\">";
```

What happens is that when I click on "Visual Mode" button first (the button that triggers my function), all the tags are correctly parsed and formatted, but if I make any change to the contents of the textarea and try to click Visual Mode again, the parser breaks right after where my edits begin. It stops recognizing the tags and just throws all the XML tags as is on the div. Since `<em>` itself is an HTML tag, everything becomes italic. What I can't understand is why adding the quotation marks would break my parsing, because I'm not even reading from the div where I added the spans. They aren't related at all.

Comment: Please give some real examples of your code, how the XML looks like, the transformation to tags, etc... other wise is very hard to make a real picture of your issue.

Comment: OK! I added this information on the post.

Comment: In jQuery, the `.html()` method outputs raw HTML without breaking and also has built in replacement as well.  I would suggest you investigate that approach instead of a `while` statement with multiple variables.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You have xml text in text area where user can type in, and you want to show the content of the the ``textarea`` in a ``div`` element also as an xml text or parsed by the browser?

Comment: In the `div` I remove the XML tags by parsing and replacing them with `<span class="sameclassasxml"> word </span>`. As the classes are predefined, I have all with different colors in CSS, so the user can "see" the XML without tags, only colored words.

Comment: Rather than escaping quotations and such, use the single quote double quote method.  Single to start and close outter most, double for all children within.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon Somehow this worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment second under the original post, "*Rather than escaping quotations and such, use the single quote double quote method. Single to start and close outter most, double for all children within.*"

Instead of:

```
var tag = "<span class=\"en ";
var tag2 = "\">";
```

Example:

```
var tag = '<span class="en "';
var tag2 = '>';
```

I believe this works fine across many programming languages.